# Does IMAP guarantee that servers send responses in order?

Tags: imap

I am implementing an IMAP client.

I think IMAP servers MUST send responses in order but I failed to find any mention about it in the [IMAP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501).

Is it guaranteed by the specification? Or do I need to prepare to accept unordered responses from IMAP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMAP servers are not required to answer in any particular order. There are some restrictions:

- an tagged response comes after all untagged responses that were caused by the same command
- OK [CLOSED] has to come after all untagged responses relating to that mailbox
- if a client's commands would otherwise be ambiguous, then the server must process then in the order received

There may be more, but I can't think of any right now. Notably, the server is *not* required to send `* FETCH...` in any particular order.

Comment: There's a few more: EXPUNGE may not be sent while no command is in progress, nor while sequence-id based commands are in progress.  The order of EXPUNGEs is significant.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP servers are neither required to send responses in order, nor they seem to be required to send the parts of a FETCH response in the same order as requested. Notably googles mail server might reorder the parts, that is if you request `BODY[1.MIME]` followed by `BODY[1]` it might return you the parts in a different order inside the fetch response.